# Numbers instead of titles for duplicate list

Tags: support, bug, duplicate-questions, revisions-list, russian-stackoverflow

Is it normal that specific revision page with a list of duplicates contains numbers instead of titles? E.g. [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/5787/4) (also probably "duplicates list edited" is lost before "from"):

> [image: ids]

But [all revisions page](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/5787/revisions) contains titles:

> [image: titles]

Comment: To close-voter: this is not ruSO specific, same behaviour for [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42690073/7).

Comment: Looks like an overlook i.e. a bug.

Comment: Well the revision list [used to show the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291830/307988), I guess they just forgot to apply the fix to specific revisions too