# Mismatch of the community specific badge icons in next badge tracker and activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges, profile-page

The graduated Stack Exchange sites except [SOFU](/q/44127/), MSE and Stack Apps (may be I missed few other sites) are have their community specific design for the badge icons.

After the recent UI changes for the profile page, in the **Next badge** tracker and **BADGES** section of the **Activity** tab, there is a mismatch with the badge icons. The community specific badges are missing in those places, instead of those the normal badge icons are displaying.

Screenshots taken from [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com).

**Next badges - Select your next badge:**

[image: Select your next badge]

**Activity tab - BADGES section:**

[image: Activity tab - Badges section]

So the mismatch with the badge icons is the [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)?

If it is by design, what was the reason to change the normal icons here instead of the site specific icons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your post made me wonder if it had been accidentally changed, so I rolled back my local copy back to verify how these items appeared prior to the update. Here's a screenshot of ELL.SE prior to the updates:

[image: ELL.SE prior to the update]

So you are correct there has been a small regression in the badge progress bars, which have now been fixed and pushed to production. The badge counts above though appear to have never used the badge icons. I'm not entirely sure why.

Anyway, it's a good suggestion so I went ahead and update the alternate badges to now use the community badge icons as well.

Here's an example of what this will look like now on ELL.SE:

[image: Activity tab: community badge icons now used]

This will also update the alternate badges and the top tags on the Profile page:

[image: Profile tab: community badge icons now used]

Thanks for catching the bug and suggestion as well!

Comment: Thanks for bring back the community specific badges.

Comment: Any chance there'll be a post for design changes like [there is for features](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l)?

Comment: @Helmar Many of the design updates are already made through discussion or bug posts (like this), so I don't see us creating a dedicated post for it. We wouldn't generate enough content for it.